# Inheriting prototype using .call(this)

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
(function() {

    LoggerBase.prototype.output = function(message) {
        console.log('LoggerBase: ' + message);
    };

    function BookAppLogger() {

        LoggerBase.call(this);

        this.logBook = function(book) {
            console.log('Book: ' + book.title);
        }
    }

    BookAppLogger.prototype = Object.create(LoggerBase.prototype);

}());
```

In this code the BookAppLogger inherits the prototypes of the LoggerBase object, I think that is clear from the last statement. What I don't understand is the purpose of the `LoggerBase.call(this)` statement. What does this line do and why is it neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BookAppLogger.prototype = Object.create(LoggerBase.prototype);
```

will only add `LoggerBase.prototype` functions to `BookAppLogger.prototype` but you cannot inherit the functions/properties that are written inside `LoggerBase` function. For example if `LoggerBase` is something like

```
function LoggerBase () {
    this.fname = "First";
    this.lname = "Last";

    this.fullname = function(){
        return this.fname + " " + this.lname;
    }
}

LoggerBase.prototype.somefunction = function(){}
```

If you do not write `LoggerBase.call(this)` inside `BookAppLogger`, then only only `LoggerBase somefunction` is inherited but not `fname, lname, fullname`

Comment: So does this mean once LoggerBase.call(this); is called inside the BookAppLogger function, the properties fname, lname and fullname are added to the BookAppLogger object? Can these properties be found in BookAppLogger.prototype or only in the BookAppLogger object?

Answer (score 0):

Its just calling the base class constructor

`LoggerBase` is a function object and the [call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) of a function can be used to call that function with a specific `this` value. Calling `LoggerBase` directly would result in `this` being the global object, which in a browser is the window object.

```
function LoggerBase() {
     console.log(this);
}

function BookAppLogger() {

    LoggerBase.call(this); // will print the book logger
    LoggerBase();          // will print the global object
}

BookAppLogger.prototype = Object.create(LoggerBase.prototype);
```